# How many days is one mandalam?

Tags: time

Everywhere there is different information (21 days, 40 days, 41 days, 42 days etc) but there is no clear answer. Please advise.

Comment: 48 afaik.......

Comment: @mar- Is this a reference to look this up anywhere?

Comment: idk, but whenever they say do sahasranama parayan for 1 mandala, that means 48 days.

Comment: Forty days: https://andhrabharati.com/dictionary/index.php?w=%E0%B0%AE%E0%B0%82%E0%B0%A1%E0%B0%B2%E0%B0%AE%E0%B1%81

Comment: Mandala can vary depending on the vrata. For example, some are two full moons and then up to Ekadashi (41 days). Sabarimala yatra etc. Some are two full moons and two new moons (48 days). This is used in Ayurveda. Basically, 40-48 days. Agama sastras for kumbhaabhisheka also follow 40-48 days depending on the auspiciousness of the 41/42/43 day etc.